# Template data not rendering in view with ExpressJS

Tags: express, swig-template

My view has:

```
{% if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') %}
    <!-- Livereload script rendered -->
    <script type="text/javascript", src="http://" + req.host  + ":35729/livereload.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

So I'd expect the `req.host` to be replaced with `localhost` or something. But what renders is:

`<script type="text/javascript", src="http://" + req.host  + ":35729/livereload.js"></script>`

My express config has: `app.set('view engine', 'html');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose your variable in the variable controls. `{{ req.host }}`

```
{% if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') %}
    <!-- Livereload script rendered -->
    <script type="text/javascript", src="http://{{ req.host }}:35729/livereload.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```